# Modal input variable from div and p

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi i wanna put data from sql into my modal inputs. I have html p tag where are variable from my database.

this is my code from div with database variables

```
<?php
    $table  = mysqli_query($connection ,'SELECT * FROM user WHERE `firstName`="Kędzierzyn-Koźle" ORDER BY `akt` DESC');
    while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){
?>
  <div class="all" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <div class="petrol-data">
      <p class="miasto" data-target="firstName"><?php echo $row['firstName']; ?></p>
      <p class="ulica" data-target="lastName"><?php echo $row['lastName']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="petrol-prices">
      <span class="petrol-name">PB 95</span>
      <p data-target="email"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></p>
      <span class="petrol-name">ON</span>
      <p data-target="diesel"><?php echo $row['diesel']; ?></p>
      <span class="petrol-name">LPG</span>
      <p data-target="lpg"><?php echo $row['lpg']; ?></p>
      <span class="petrol-name">PB 98</span>  
      <p data-target="vebenzyna"><?php echo $row['vebenzyna']; ?></p>
      <span class="petrol-name">ON PREMIUM</span>
      <p data-target="dizver"><?php echo $row['dizver']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-div">
      <div class="akt"><p style="font-size:7px;" ><span class="bold">Ostatnia Aktualizacja: </span><?php echo $row['akt']; ?>
        <span class="bold" data-target="nick"> Dodał/a: </span><?php echo $row['nick']; ?></p></div>
        <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>"><div class="edit"><p>Edytuj</p></div></a>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php }


       ?>
```

Here is my ajax code to modal inputs from old project where sql variables was in a table

```
$(document).on('click','a[data-role=update]',function(){

            var id  = $(this).data('id');

            var firstName  = $('#'+id).children('.miasto').text();

            var lastName  = $'#'+id).children('td[data-target=lastName]').text();

            var email  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=email]').text();

            var diesel  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=diesel]').text();

            var lpg  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=lpg]').text(lpg);

            var vebenzyna  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=vebenzyna]').text();

            var dizver  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=dizver]').text();

            var nick  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=nick]').text();
```

Comment: var firstName give me a variable but from all database

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want.